# simple client and server

Tags: c

can sum guide me to a link or a program for simple client and server c or c++ code to run on linux

The requirement is that should be able to send and receive messages.....

Answer (score 3):

[Beej's Guide to Network Programming - Using Internet Sockets](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html) is an excellent tutorial to understand sockets and connections. Plus it contains basic server-client sample applications.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the [Paul Griffiths' Echo server](http://www.paulgriffiths.net/program/c/echoserv.php).  It's a simple echo server and client written in C.  It's written using some unix headers though, and will not work on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

/* insert why didnt you google this comment */

[here's one](http://www.tenouk.com/Module40c.html)

Comment: I googled ,but tat any 1 of u had a better links....Thanks this is great...........................

Comment: lol...my google was "simple client server program in c"..it was the first one. Im not bashing you here because i find the same problem with myself. Its not usually that the answers aren't out there its about knowing how to look for them!