# where should i start to learn how to write a server in C?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [simple client and server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824496/simple-client-and-server)

I want to learn how to code a server in C, preferentially using threads, but i don't know where to start. I just want to learn the real basics to improve it gradually, so i think i want to code something simple first, like an echo server. can anyone help me?

Comment: What OS do you want to code for?

Comment: What kind of server do you want to write? If network programming is your main interest, then [Beej's guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/index.html) might be of use.

Comment: @Bart: +1 for Beej ... but the official location , according to Beej himself, is [http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/).

Comment: @Bart: I just wanted to post that as an answer when I read your comment in full. :( Definitly one of the best things aroung, for both C and C++

Comment: @pmg Thanks. Just had that link in my bookmarks @Xeo Agree. I didn't add it as an answer yet though because I would have liked some clarification from the OP first on what exactly he wants.

Comment: @cnicutar: Reason being?

Comment: @Xeo Despite the fact the examples are mostly correct (if not entirely) the explanations are poor. I've seen so many people coming with those examples (on this site and on others) and sounding clueless. I've looked through the explanations: rubbish. The code is hardly commented, the user copy-pastes bs and doesn't understand a thing.

Comment: I know lots of people used that guide; it's kind of sad. Many many many (many) still think the only difference between tcp and udp is that "udp is unreliable". "In that, the man pages are no use, as you've probably discovered." - rubbish. I could write a bigger guide than the entire guide listing its deficiencies.

Comment: @cnicutar Any "proper" suggestions then that you might have for the OP?

Comment: @Bart Sure, "Unix Network Programming". Still, calling that merely "proper" is an offense.

Comment: wow! thank you for the comments! even if @cnicutar is right, this beej's guide is just what i've been looking for for a starting point. thanks everyone! and i guess i'll code for linux. also, @Bart please post as an answer so i can accept it (:

Comment: @cnicutar Thanks for the info, much appreciated. Glad I could be offensive on a Saturday evening. ;) Perhaps add it as an answer?

Comment: @Bart You weren't. If my tone was harsh, if my language was inappropriate, I am sorry. I guess we can agree to disagree :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are interested in Network Programming then [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) might be of interest.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest getting the Stevens TCP/IP Illustrated series.  There is example code which walks you through that sort of thing.  Yes, it goes into a great deal of detail not 100% necessary to just write a simple TCP server, but it very good none-the-less.

You might also want to take a peek at the ttcp.c source code.  It hooks standard in to the network to standard out.  eg:

```
host b> ttcp -r | tar xf -
host a> tar cf - . | ttcp -t b
```

Though simply running:

```
host b> ttcp -r
host a> ttcp -t b
```

Should show you the concepts.

Answer (score 2):

I can also suggest, using a third-party library like [Apache Runtime Library](http://apr.apache.org/), mostly used by the famus webserver. It's better if you want to write portable applications. Here is the [latest documentation](http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/1.4/).